# How to stop a previous if-else statement to print every time in the new condition?

Tags: python

I made this program for finding out you age based on your birthday.

```
print"Let's find your exact age using your birthday!"
d1=int(input("Enter your date of birth:-"))
d1=int(d1)
m1=int(input("Enter your month of birth:-"))
m1=int(m1)
y1=int(input("Enter your year of birth:-"))
y1=int(y1)
d2=int(input("Enter todays date:-"))
d2=int(d2)
m2=int(input("Enter the month we are in:-"))
m2=int(m2)
y2=int(input("Enter the year right now:-"))
y2=int(y2)
rd= y2-y1
md= abs(m2-m1)
dd= abs(d2-d1)
if md > 0:
    print("You will be", rd,"years old in",md, "months and", dd,"days!")
else:
    print("You will be", rd,"years old in", dd, "days")
if dd > 0:
    print("You will be", rd,"years old in",md, "months and", dd,"days!")
else:
    print("You will be", rd,"years old in",md,"months.")
if (md > 0 and
    dd > 0):
    print("You will be", rd,"years old in",md, "months and", dd,"days!")
else:
    print("You are",rd, "years old! And it's your birthday! Happy       Birthdaay!!!")
```

I wanted to to make the last if-else condition print "happy birthday" exclusively when both the md and dd are less than 0 but whats happening is that because of the previous conditions the output is in the form:

```
('You will be', 16, 'years old in', 0, 'days')
('You will be', 16, 'years old in', 0, 'months.')
('You are', 16, "years old! And it's your birthday! Happy Birthdaay!!!")
```

How do i correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to rethink your logic a bit. Here's one way to do what you want:

```
if md == 0 and dd == 0:
        print "You are", rd, "years old! And it's your birthday! Happy Birthdaay!!!"
elif md == 0:
        print "You will be", rd, "years old in", dd, "days"
elif dd == 0:
        print "You will be", rd, "years old in", md, "months"
else:
        print "You will be", rd, "years old in", md, "months and", dd, "days!"
```

This uses `elif`, which is a combination of `else` and `if`: it only executes if the preceding `if` (or `elif`) condition was false and its own condition is true. In the above code, we are guaranteed that only one message is printed.

A side note: As you may have noticed, this program doesn't quite work for calculating the time to someone's birthday. You'll have to do some more complex calculations for `rd`, `md`, and `dd` in order to get it working in all cases.